# How do I prevent Rails from checking a unique constraint against the object being edited/updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5, updates, unique-constraint

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this model with a unique constraint

```
class UserNotification < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :crypto_currency

  validates_uniqueness_of :buy, scope: [:user_id, :crypto_currency_id]

end
```

I use this method to handle updates to the model

```
  def update
    @user_notification = UserNotification.new(user_notification_params)
    @user_notification.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_notification.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_notifications_path, notice: 'Updated successfully.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        @crypto_currencies = CryptoCurrency.where(id: CryptoIndexCurrency.all.pluck(:crypto_currency_id).uniq).order(:name)
        puts "full messages: #{@user_notification.errors.full_messages}"
      end
    end
  end
```

Even though there is only one entry in my database, when I invoke the above method on the existing entry, I get the error in my model complaining about the unique constraint being violated (the else branch is called) ...

```
    Buy has already been taken
```

How do I prevent the item from checking a unique constraint against itself?  That is, if there is only one entry in the database, a unique constraint should never be thrown if we are editing that one entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@user_notification = UserNotification.new(user_notification_params)
```

to

```
# I assume that you have id in your params
@user_notification = UserNotification.find(params[:id])
@user_notification.assign_attributes(user_notification_params)
```

When you are doing `UserNotification.new(user_notification_params)` and then trying to `.save` your record, Rails makes an `INSERT`, that's why you are getting uniqueness validation error.

When you call [assign_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes), your existing model will be populated with new values without saving. Then you change it's `user` to `current_user` and call save, which will send an `UPDATE` query to the database.

And of course `UserNotification`'s `id` should be a separate param. It shouldn't be included in `user_notification_params`. You need it only to find a required record in database.